# CryptoPRO DSS-LITE - Подпись PDF не определена (невалидна) + сертификат ненадежный

Tags: плагин, сертификат, криптопро, csp

друзья!

Задача:

Разработать сервис для подписи pdf (под стандарты 2019г), используя клиентскую подпись (browser plugin). Сервис нужен для интеграции в наши существующие ИС.

9 месяцев назад задавал вопрос на форуме криптоПро:

Ссылка на форум: https://www.cryptopro.ru/forum2/default.aspx?g=posts&m=89574#post89574

До сих пор разбираюсь с DSS LITE.
Что сделано:

1) Куплено: DSS-LITE, TSP (client,server), OCSP (client,server), CSP 4, SVS.
`КриптоПро DSS LITE - для подписи - 600 000
КриптоПро SVS - для проверки 225 000
КриптоПро OCSP Server - для проверки статуса сертификата от Реестра УЦ и получения ответа на момент формирования подписи - 225 000
КриптоПро TSP - для нанесения штампа времени и OCSP ответа 225 000
КриптоПро .Net - фреймворк для SVS
КриптоПро CSP - серверная`

2) Написан фронтенд (VUE.js) и бекенд (php (SOAP)):

PHP: https://m.vk.com/doc40778210_483856329

C#:

`tt = cr.PreSignDocument(document, SignatureType, true, rawCertificate, arr);
...
byte[] crpdf = cr.PostSignDocument(tt.СacheObjectId,tt.HashValue, document, SignatureType,true, arr);`

Код C# (для теста): https://codepen.io/kostia7alania/pen/ZVYdGM

ДЕМО: https://photos.app.goo.gl/LpsT2vmndNtnZTge6

Всё аккуратненько конспектируется в топике в ВК: https://vk.com/topic-125614288_37412431

---

Так вот. Через наш фронт и php подписывается невалидно.
Вчера, в качестве теста, также написали на скорую руку на C# (без участия фронта, просто подставив готовые значения), передаем уже точно как в документации пишут - "массив байт" (byte[]), а результат один и тот же - невалидная подпись.

Пример невалидно подписанного PDF - https://vk.com/doc40778210_483748935

Пример без штампа времени - https://vk.com/doc40778210_483755806

Скрин о невалидном сертификате в Adobe Reader с плагином от крипты:
[image]

Если подсунуть эту PDF-ку в криптоАРМ, пишет, что подпись недействителен или документ был изменен (целостность нарушена или что-то такое) и такое:
[image]

---

Сейчас возникают вопросы (!спасибо за великолепную документацию!): в чем отличие между **signHashValue** и **signValue**. Подписываю хеш дока на фронте, получаю хеш подписи (это **signHashValue**), тогда что за **signValue**? Откуда брать значение подписи?

[image]

Собственно, через Адоб и КриптоАрм подписывает успешно усиленной подписью как со штампом времени, так и без!

**UPD**
то есть, на фронте запускаю **signData**(dataBase64:String, certThumbprint:String), которая возвращает base64 закодированную подпись - значит это **signValue**, а тогда что **signHashValue**??

Использую - **RusCryptoJS** (https://aleksandr-ru.github.io/RusCryptoJS/cryptopro.html)

Comment: 1. перейти на openssl, использовать `Mono.Security`, 2. данные ms надо реверсировать по байтам, Big/Lite Indianes, на этом пути вас ждёт увлекательное путешествие в мир несовместимостей MS решений. 3. написать часть крипта на чистом С, используя openssl.

Comment: @NewView, можно с Вами связаться? Или здесь позадавать вопросы.

Comment: @NewView, это нерелевантный ответ. У нас DSS-LITE!

Comment: Это не ответ, это совет :) если есть вопросы, задавайте, попробую ответь. И все что умеет DSS, это по сути то-же самое что умеет openssl из коробки. DSS имеет смысл использовать там, где обязательна работа с токенами, из за АПИ. А так это по сути при CryptoAPI от микрософт, без изменений.

Comment: А в первом пункте вашего сообщения это цены на изделия криптопро? Только обратил внимание 

Comment: все!поучилось! на С# тренировались с кодировкой. осталось допилить на бое и тогда выложу в паблик